# creating OMR image for folding machine on each page with JasperReports

Tags: java, image, image-processing, jasper-reports, omr

Our invoicing system needs to print OMR (optical mark recognition) symbol on each page of our invoices so the folding machine knows what to put in the envelope, so that little PNG picture has to be put on each page. 
  Our invoice is consisted of main report with two subreports created in special `.jrxml` files. Picture is generated by calling web service with passing page number as a parameter in http request. So, we need to incorporate picture into subreport hoping that subreport will 'know' actual page number when generating document. Error we are getting is:

```
Error filling print... Could not resolved style(s): pdf 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not resolved style(s): pdf      at 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.checkUnresolvedReferences(JRFillObjectFactory.java:1610)      at 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.setStyles(JRFillObjectFactory.java:1537)      at 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.loadStyles(JRBaseFiller.java:962)      at 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:835)      at 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:782)      at 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:532)      at 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:63)      at
 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner.run(JRThreadSubreportRunner.java:209)      at
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

We are using `JasperReports 3.0.0` - migration to newer version requires lot of changes, so that's for now out of option, in case we need to go to newer version.

Comment: .. and if I put image into subreport I am risking having two OMR images on one page, what is not appropriate. I need an image on page level..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved with putting picture onto band called 'background' of main report. Picture is being shown regularly on each page once.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great application called Mail Markup that will put OMR marks on any document you like. It allows you to configure the OMR marks to your requirements so it is compatible with any folder inserter. You can find out more and download an evaluation [here](http://www.mailmarkup.com)